# Search site that requires a username and password

Tags: php, asp.net

I would like to be able to pull some data from a website.

The website needs to have a USERNAME, PASSWORD and a KEY

I know how to pull the data I want from a website that does not require a username/password.

I do have a username and password and key for the site.

The site is ASPX.

When i login the the URL looks like:

https://admin.sitename.com/portal.aspx

I am looking for a way to be able to authenticate using PHP

Or if there is a better idea that I can look into.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in normally, then just copying all your cookies into the cookie jar PHP/Curl is using.